# Reference return type of member functions to custom classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I have the following code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std ; 

class abc{
public :
    string name;
    abc & change_name(string s);
};

abc & abc::change_name(string s) {
    this->name = s;
    return *this;
};

int main(){
    abc obj1 ;
    abc temp ; 
    temp = obj1.change_name("abhi");

cout<<"Name is : "<<obj1.name<<endl; \\Prints - Name is : abhi
cout<<"Name is : "<<temp.name<<endl;  \\Prints -Name is : abhi
\\cout<<"Name is  "<<temp->name<<endl;  \\\\Error : base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'abc'.
    return 0;
}
```

The member function `change_name(string s)`,of the class `abc` ,returns a pointer of the type `abc` . Inside the main , i have a `temp` object of type `abc`, which is not a pointer .My question is how does the statement `temp = obj1.change_name("abhi")` work, when the return type of `change_name(string s)` is a pointer but `temp` is not a pointer itself ?

Comment: `abc::change_name()` returns a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: Corrected.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
abc & abc::change_name(string s) {
    this->name = s;
    return *this;
};
```

does not return a pointer. It returns a reference to the current object.

So in this statement

```
temp = obj1.change_name("abhi");
```

there is used the default copy assignment operator. In fact this statement is equivalent to

```
temp = obj1;
```

You may consider a reference to an object as its, object, alias.

A function that would return a pointer could look the following way

```
abc * abc::change_name(string s) {
    this->name = s;
    return this;
};
```

Compare your original program with this lightly updated program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std ; 

class abc{
public :
    string name;
    abc * change_name(string s);
};

abc * abc::change_name(string s) {
    this->name = s;
    return this;
};

int main(){
    abc obj1 ;
    abc *temp ; 
    temp = obj1.change_name("abhi");

    cout<<"Name is  "<<temp->name<<endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP didn't realize that `temp = obj1` was a deep copy rather than a pointer/reference copy, since most languages copy by reference.